# Grails: WAR file deployment : Finding the port

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

I have a Grails 2.3.6 app running as a WAR file in a server. Currently it's running in Tomcat 7.

In future we might have the app run in other servers too.

Now the problem i face is unique. In one of the service groovy files i need to get the port number for the running app.

For Tomcat the port number is set in **server.xml** and one potential way to get that will be to read from there.

But am looking for a more generic solution. So that even if the WAR file is deployed in other type of servers, i could get the port number.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The* port (singular) isn't necessarily well-defined, e.g. you can have a Tomcat configured with several connectors listening on different ports, or serving both http and https.  In the context of a particular request you can talk about "the port" that that request was received on, but then what happens if your app is behind a reverse proxy or load balancer...

The only reliable approach is to manually specify the appropriate port number/URL/whatever in a configuration file (e.g. a `grails.config.locations` external).

Comment: I would still like to explore the possibility of dynamically getting the port number irrespective of the server where the app is running :-)

Comment: @donguy76 read my answer again - there is simply _no_ reliable way to do this. A typical webapp I'm working on now runs in a tomcat with two connectors, on ports 8456 and 8457, which are behind an Apache httpd reverse proxy exposing them to the world on ports 80 and 443 respectively. Which of those four numbers do you consider to be "the" port number of this app?

Comment: No idea! So my question will be, if there's no proxies involved then is there a reliable way of getting the port number?

Comment: @donguy76 only in the context of one particular request, using `ServletRequest.getServerPort()` or `ServletRequest.getLocalPort()` (accessible via the `RequestContextHolder` as suggested in another answer).  If you're not on a request handling thread (i.e. your service was called from BootStrap or a background thread like a Quartz job, rather than from a controller) then no.

Comment: I tried that from the Job & Bootstrap groovy files and both didn't work. So is there a good place to put that code to get the port number?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to set the `grails.serverURL` configuration property to the base root of the application. In the `development` environment, this is typically something like

```
grails.serverURL = "https://localhost:8080/example"
```

and in the `production` environment

```
grails.serverURL = "https://example.org"
```

If you don't set this correctly, certain things won't work, e.g. generating absolute URLs. If this property is set correctly, then getting the port in a service is as simple as:

```
class MyService {

  def grailsApplication

  Integer getPort() {
    String basePath = grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL
    // parse out the path (exercise for reader)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid hard coding the address + port in the config.froovy file.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the port in the service you can get it from HttpServletRequest as follows:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
def port = request.getServerPort()
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't see the Grails app throwing an exception. When i try to debug, it get's to that line and goes somewhere else. And the reason i say it's not working is because, the code after that is not getting executed.