# get server port value from running application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on the Spring boot((v2.1.2.RELEASE) application that will be deployed to the existing tomcat server on Linux box.
How can I get the value of port# in the code? I have to record this value for logging.
Since I don't config the port# on my application, I cannot use server.port and etcs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Ernesto's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910238/2568649, in a war deployed Spring Boot or Spring MVC controller I believe you can just include the HttpServletRequest as one of the method arguments, and so can get the port from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

- serverProperties :

  ```java
  @Autowired
  private ServerProperties serverProperties;
  int port= serverProperties.getPort();
  ```
- ServletWebServerApplicationContext:

  ```java
  @Autowired
  private ServletWebServerApplicationContext webServerAppCtxt;
  int port = webServerAppCtxt.getWebServer().getPort();
  ```